# How does kernel decide stack size

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, stack-overflow

Just wondering when process starts how is its stack requirements determined, or does every process starts with default stack size and that dynamically grows depending on requirement.
On my system the soft limit on stack size is `10M` and hard limit is `unlimited`. Does that mean that stack can grow up to max available RAM?
If i have a dozen threads in my process, will stack size of all be different( assuming that i don't set stack attribute)

Comment: IMHO `man rlimit` gives all the answers.

Comment: @wildplasser IMHO you have not understood what i was asking

Comment: The kernel does not decide stack size of threads. The `pthread_create` function does setup the stack of every thread.

Answer (score 1):

Each process is started with a minimally sized userspace stack, which is automatically expanded as needed.

If the soft limit is breached then the process will be terminated.  The process may raise its own soft limit, but no higher than the hard limit.

Even if the soft limit is unlimited, the maximum useable stack size is limited by the other mappings in the process's address space, since it must be contiguous.